# Load an other page with changing url

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a site with a page like `www.machin.com` and i have a script which update the url without reloading the page.
It becomes `www.machin.com/bidule` but if I want to load this i have a 404 error, normal it doesn't exist. 
Do the link with a htaccess causes the lost of my link in the html because the directory doesn't exit neither.

I want the loading of `www.machin.com` when i load the page `www.machin.com/bidule` but i don't know how do this with angularJS or JQuery.

Ben

Comment: you are talking about the routing and templating capability of AngularJS (and also about partials and single page applications)
one such tutorial is here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/routes.html

Comment: I already use that but if a write the url `www.machin.com/bidule` and press "enter" , i found nothing, logic i don't have a page that exist.
If a created a page in php with a header to load the other it would work no ? Even if it's not my favourite solution ^^

Comment: i dont really know much about php. you can edit question and add the php tag to attract the right people for that.

Comment: Finally i created the directories, it's better for me. Thanks for your time anyway :)